# How does printf know when it's being passed a signed int

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to figure out how variables really work in C and find it strange how the `printf` function seems to know the difference between different variables of the same size, I'm assuming they're both 16 bits.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned short int positive = 0xffff;
    short int negative = 0xffff;

    printf("%d\n%d\n", positive, negative);
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
65535
-1
```

Comment: You tell it — that's what `%d` says.  The arguments after the format string are subject to default argument promotion rules — `unsigned short` and `short` are both converted to `int` (but they're converted to different `int` values under normal circumstances) before `printf()` is called.  (See C11 [§6.5.2.2 Function calls ¶6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6) for details.)

Comment: Try with `unsigned` and `int` since it should have the size `%d` expects (no short->int extension), say 4 bytes, and using that `int` size for the assignment, i.e. `0xffffffff`, and printf will not produce miracles anymore... @JonathanLeffler You should write an answer, this is an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

I think we have to more carefully distinguish between the type conversions on the different integer types on one hand and the `printf` format specifiers (allowing to force `printf` how to interpret the data) on the other hand.

Systematically:

```
printf("%hd %hd\n", positive, negative);
// gives: -1 -1
```

Both values are interpreted as *signed short int* by `printf`, regardless of the declaration.

```
printf("%hu %hu\n", positive, negative);
// gives: 65535 65535
```

Both values are interpreted as *unsigned short int* by `printf`, regardless of the declaration.

However,

```
printf("%d %d\n", positive, negative);
// gives: 65535 -1
```

Both values are implicitly converted to (a longer) *int*, while the sign is kept.

Finally,

```
printf("%u %u\n", positive, negative);
// gives 65535 4294967295
```

Again, both values are implicitly converted to *int*, while the sign is kept, but then the negative value is interpreted as unsigned. As we can see here, plain `int` is actually 32-bit (on this system).

---

Curiously, only if I compile with `gcc` and `-Wpedantic`, it gives me a warning for the assignment `short int negative = 0xffff;`.